# Spark StructType VS Case Class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I understand that `Case Class` are minimal regular classes and `StructType` is a spark Datatype which is a collection of `StructFields`.

But we can use both `Case Class` and `StructType` to create Dataframes and other use cases in a similar way.

Wanted to understand

- in what scenarios we should **prefer One over the other** and WHY ?
- Are there some scenarios where we have to use one of them, and not possible to use the other?

Comment: See that video from the Scala World Conference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXipqCcVmQM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LafWXI37mcw

Answer (score 0):

There is no real aspect that defines which one is better now.

`Case` had a limit of 22 fields, but that is no longer the case.

It strikes me that `case` is easier to work with than defining the Structs. Answer irt data frames.